# Передача рабочего стола сервера на клиент

Tags: delphi

Нужно передавать изображение рабочего стола сервера в реальном времени на клиент. Delphi.
По какому протоколу лучше? Как сжимать кадры?

Comment: Вам обязательно свое? Есть много готовых решений.

Comment: Необязательно.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, до кучи тогда стандартный виндовый RemoteDesktop, бесплатные [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/ru/index.aspx), [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) и [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/RU/). Последний работает в окне браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Из готовых личная рекомендация - [Remote Manipulator System](http://rmansys.ru/downloads/), авторы - наши ребята, штука за год использования нареканий не имела. Дома сгорел монитор, поэтому комп соединен с ноутом по сети и на ноуте запущен RMS-Viewer =) Частота кадров - не для игр, но при работе не заметно. Можно настроить под трафик/под цвет/под FPS. 
*Есть бесплатная версия - ей и пользуюсь*

*ЗЫ* смотрите функционал на сайте - мне кажется, для решения большинства задач больше ничего ставить не придется.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно организовать просмотр, или управление удаленным рабочим столом, используя протокол RDP. Есть даже специальные библиотеки для работы с ним в Delphi (можно найти в интернете). 
Второй вариант использовать TCP/IP. В этом случае имеется несколько проблем:

1. Если просто передавать снимки экрана, то это грозит мерцаниями при просмотре.
2. Лучше для этих целей использовать не готовые компоненты, а писать, напрямую обращаясь к сокетам
3. Чтобы избавиться от мерцания, нужно использовать драйвер видеозахвата. Подобным образом работает, например, Radmin